# how to create linebreak in output on pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

i want to create linebreak on pycharm.

```
colors=["red","yellow","brown","green","orange"]
for i in colors:
    print(i)
print("""""")
for i in range(len(colors)):
    print(i)
print("""""")
for i in range(1,len(colors)):
    print(i,colors[i])
```

[here how code execute in output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOM2G.png)

Comment: Just `print()` will print a line-break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python every print also prints a "linebreak" at the end.
but if you want to add extra linebreaks, you can also do this:

```
print("\n")
```

or if want to print a the output of a variable as well you can do this:

```
print(some_variable, "\n")
```

as you can see a "linebreak" or new line is just this part `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer as formatting in comments is difficult. I will edit this in due course.

This will work for you.

```
colors=["red","yellow","brown","green","orange"]
for i in colors:
    print(i)
print('\n')
for i in range(len(colors)):
    print(i)
print('\n')
for i in range(1,len(colors)):
    print(i,colors[i])
```

Comment: thanks, is there any other statement for line break or just this?

Comment: Just focus on this.